# product of root multiplicities in Kac Moody Algebras

Tags: kac-moody-algebras

Let $\mathfrak{g}$ be a Kac-Moody Algebra with GCM $A$. Let $\alpha$ and $\beta$ be two roots not necessarily real and $g_\alpha$ and $g_\beta$ be the corresponding weight spaces of dimension $ \text{mult}\, \alpha$ and $\text{mult}\, \beta$.

My question is: Does the number $k = \text{mult}\, \alpha \times \text{mult}\, \beta$ have 'any' interpretation in Lie theory? Like $k$ is also the dimension of some weight spaces of some other Lie algebras which are in some way connected to $\mathfrak{g}$ or in some tensor products of $\mathfrak{g}$ or something  like that.

I want to interpret this number $k$ in terms some Lie theory objects. Any suggestion is welcomed.

Thanks for your valuable time.

Comment: This question looks very open-ended, so it would be better motivated if you could point to some specific example where there is an interesting interpretation of the product.    (By the way, I added one tag, since the usual finite dimensional semisimple Lie algebras are examples of Kac-Moody algebras.  Of course, in those cases $k$ is always 1.)

Comment: Trivial comment: the Lie bracket goes from $\mathfrak g \otimes \mathfrak g \to \mathfrak g$, so your appeal to "tensor products of $\mathfrak g$" is not completely unreasonable.

Comment: Cross-posted to MathSE http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1636050/

Comment: @JimHumphreys I have explored the Lie theory literature as much as I can (most of the standard books and some papers). but I could not find single place where this product occurs. So I couldnt point to one particular example. sorry.I am interested in this number because it occuring in my research. so I want to understand it better. So if any one can show me one single occurence of this number in the literature, that would itself very much helpful. Thanks a lot.